# python static code analysis tools - code analysis (preliminary research question)

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, pylint

Disclaimer:
I've just started researching this area/domain of knowledge; so I have no idea what exactly it's called; but through a google search, I believe it has to do with (static code analysis, or at least it's related to it).

My question is:
Given a python code - file - script - module - package. Is there a tool that can produce a report out of it detailing:
how many classes are used, functions, built-in functions; decorators ;if/for/while statements etc?

To give you an analogy most of us can relate to:
Given a text file: find all the verbs / nouns / adjectives / adverbs / proper noun.
NLP tools like spaCy or NLTK have the ability to do that for natural languages.

But what about programming languages? Is there a tool for that?
Can a tool like pylint do that?

**UPDATE**

As I expected such tools exist; one of them as @BoarGules suggested in his comment is the ast module ... It's the hint I needed to go further in my research; any further suggestions are welcome. BTW ast stands for abstract syntax tree.

Comment: Maybe you should look at the `ast` module.

Comment: @BoarGules I've just heard of it from you, I will take your reply into consideration.

Comment: like the comment says, python exposes its own language syntax tree through ast

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html Pydoc ? Not sure it is what you are looking for ... your code has to be documented

Comment: The source code of [Python](http://python.org/) is [open source](https://opensource.org/) and downloadable. It is coded partly in C, and partly in Python. You are allowed to download it and study it. See also [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) and [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) European projects.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That will be an arduous endeavor for a beginner like myself; it's like learning English grammar by studying Latin grammar:)

Comment: Actually, Latin grammar is much easier (since more regular) than English one. I studied both, but my native language is French (and Russian is the language my parents spoke to me). For static analysis of C code, look into [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com). Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem) and of [Abstract Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation)

Comment: pylint uses the Astroid library, maybe you should have a look on its capabilities

Answer (score 1):

> Given a python code - file - script - module - package. Is there a tool that can produce a report out of it detailing: how many classes are used...

#### There cannot be an exact tool for that, since Python has an [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) primitive.

When that primitive is executed, the set of classes or functions of your Python program can increase.

Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Consider using [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation) and [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) techniques in your Python static analyzer.

Consider also using (painfully) [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) on the source code (the code written in C) of the Python interpreter. With a lot of work, Frama-C could be extended to analyze Python source code.

Read also recent proceedings of [ACM SIGPLAN](https://sigplan.org/) conferences.